# VBA application on excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA with an application to automate excel with some operations in an spreadsheet. However I don't know how to copy cells programmatically.

I tried using this code:

```
Form1.ex.Range(r1.Text + ":" + r1x.Text).Activate()
Form1.ex.ActiveCell.Copy(Destination:=Form1.ex.Range(c1.Text + ":" + c2.Text))
```

Where `r1` is what I copy from, and then `r1x` contains the text of both `r1` and `r1x`. It basically selects a range of cells and is then meant to copy them, but it didn't work well.

How can I fix this code to copy a cell from one location to another?

Comment: I added your code and explanation from the comments to your question and also tidied up your question a bit. Have a look at how I formatted the code since you said you had trouble with it before, [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is also a useful resource. If you could [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31963740/edit) to explain how this code 'didn't work well' it would help anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: "r1x contains the text of both r1 and r1x." - What do you mean here?

Comment: ah, seems SuperBiasedMan edited it wrongly, but thanks anyway :3 
btw grade, look how i'll explain it
i need to copy about 8 or 9 cells, so i decided to create first cell and last cell, so it would be easily to copy, e.g: A1:A9 instead of A1,A2,A3,etc..
r1 is the first cell (A1)
r1x is the last cell (A9)
so i wanna copy all this (A1 to A9) range

Comment: What are r1, r1x, c1, and c2? Are those shapes that you've created? Are they meant to be cells? Because if they are meant to be cells, you are using the .Text function when I would expect .Formula or .Value. My recommendation would be to have your variables set to equal specific cells in your spreadsheet, which you then Name specially to be able to reference them in your code regardless of how those cells move when columns / rows are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this how to do a copy :

```
'Copy range A1:A9 from Sheet1 to Sheet2 A1 :
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1" & ":" & "A9").Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

'With your references :
Form1.ex.Range(r1.Text & ":" & r1x.Text).Copy _
    Destination:=Form1.ex.Range(c1.Text)
```

In your example you use Form1 and ex, if they are respectively a workbook and a sheet, the code would work, but if it is an UserForm, this won't.

Don't use `+` to concatenate strings, it is the operator `&`